# Guard doesn't retrieve data from store (NGRX)

Tags: ngrx

i have a problem protecting my routes using the store, when ever i tried to select some variable from the store its undefined and my page doesn't load because of that.

The store is working fine, here some pictures.

[Initial State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uk2zX.png)

[State loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZBt6.png)

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msg6L.png)

i recreate the problem here 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngrx-guard-not-working

its the guard called before the store is init?

what can i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to select the `projects` from the `campaigns`, your selector should look like this:

```
export const getCampaigns = createFeatureSelector<any>('campaigns');
export const getProjectState = createSelector(getCampaigns, state => state.projects);
```